# Pandas left join on string contains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

How can I implement this Pyspark code with **Pandas Dataframes**?

`result = df.join(df2, df.name.contains(df2.text), "left")`

df

[image]

df2

[image]

result

[image]

**P.D: df and df2 are Big Data tables**

---

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: It will help if you can give more details in your question, especially what exactly you want to achieve and what code you have already tried?

Comment: a left join based on string contains

Comment: i have added a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering ops added constrain of scalability, i solved this with a lambda and a helper function

```
import pandas as pd

def helper(str1, str2):
    out = 'null'
    if str2 in str1:
        out = str2
    return out

names = ['auriel', 'michael', 'karl']
text = ['iel', 'ael', 'nov']

df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['name'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(text, columns=['text'])

result = pd.DataFrame(zip(df.name, df2.text), columns=['name', 'text'])
result['text'] = result.apply(lambda x: helper(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)

print(result)

      name  text
0   auriel   iel
1  michael   ael
2     karl  null
```

Comment: will perform well with df and df2 of 100.00 rows?

Comment: i dont know what well exactly means in your case, but the edited solution is much faster than my original try

Answer (score 1):

**Pyspark**

Iam not sure if text will always be the last three characters. I therefore slice name using the text column. If its going to be always last three characters, then we can simplify it.

```
new = (df.withColumn('text',regexp_extract('name', ('|').join(df1.select('text').rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()), 0))#Use df1 column to slice name and create join column
           
           .join(df1, how='left', on='text')#Join
          ).show()
```

**Pandas**

```
  new =(df.assign(text=df['name'].str.extract(fr"({('|').join(df1['text'].to_list())})")#Extract df1 text from name into new column
       ).merge(df1, how='left', on='text')#merge
     )


     name text
0   Auriel  iel
1  Michael  ael
2     Karl  NaN
```

Comment: this is not pandas, but thnks

Comment: See my edit. I assumed you needed a pyspark or pandas answer based on the tags

Comment: the lenght of the text is random

Comment: Yes, thats why I have used text column in one to edit  name in df before matching. Thats should work

Comment: Please accept the answer if you issue is resolved